# Get Length of String using Jquery on MVC 4 ASP .NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I made a simple form where you write a string, and then print it on another view, but now i have to check the length of the string(using jquery) and print it on a Jquery UI dialog, already looked for some tutorials but im new to this MVC4 ASP .Net so its a little bit confusing to use jquery(which I have to) on this framework.

Here is the view of the form:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Página principal";
}

<h3>Formulario</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm())

{
    @Html.Label("Escribe lo que quieras")<br />
    @Html.TextArea("text")<br />

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>


}
```

Here is the view where i print the string i got from the first view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Hola, Escribiste: ";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>

<script type="text/javascript">

       var myLength = $("#text").val().length;



       </script>
```

And here is the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication10.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modifique esta plantilla para poner en marcha su aplicación ASP.NET MVC.";

            return View();

       }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string text)
        {
            TempData["Text"] = text;
            return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = TempData["Text"];

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Página de contacto.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: It looks like it would be much easier to do this in javascript rather than via MVC on the server. In the code which opens the jQuery dialog, you can listen to its `open` event then use normal jQuery to find where to put the string length and insert it using `.html()` or whatever. If you post the code for opening your jQuery dialog and where the length needs to be displayed we may be able to help you with that.

Comment: Using jQuery is no different whether you're using MVC, WebForms or static HTML so the MVC side of things is largely irrelevant. Can you isolate what problems you're having with writing the JavaScript?

Comment: You have to look at the id of the Textarea. Usually asp.net ids are hierarchical build depending on your generated dom like `ìd="parentid_parentid_textareaid"` to stay unique.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to bear in mind that jQuery (and jQuery UI) are client-side technologies.  That code runs in the user's browser.  ASP.Net MVC is a server-side technology.  That code runs on your server, and creates the HTML and JavaScript that is delivered to the browser.

You seem to be off to a reasonable start.  You are outputting JavaScript code that will run in the browser and set the length of the string in a JavaScript variable

```
var myLength = $("#text").val().length;
```

Now, you need to add some additional code to create your jQuery UI dialog.  You put that JavaScript code in your view as well.  ASP.Net will then send that code to the browser as well, where it will run.

Have a look at the examples for jQuery UI dialogs and try to incorporate that into your view

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Fundamentally you will have a block of HTML that describes what will appear in the dialog, e.g.:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>The length of the string is: <span id='len'>RESULT HERE</span></p>
</div>
```

and will "convert" that block into the dialog using a call like:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
</script>
```

The only trick now is to update the text in that dialog to show the length of the string.  There are many ways to accomplish that.  One way is to have an HTML element as a placeholder for that value, and set the text of that element using jQuery:

```
$('#len').text(myLength);
```

Comment: im not getting it bro